SwiftUI EditMode not working properly in ListView
TLDR: Move Indicators did not appear in List EditMode even after the moveDisabled modifier value is false(dynamically updated).
Hello guys, I'm here to ask about the editMode in listView that made me cry for over 2 days. I know that editMode in ListView is still flakey, but I want some help here.
The problem is: When we move items inside listView using the onMove Modifier it works fine until we use the moveDisabled modifier for items inside ForEach.
The real problem begins when we tryin' to add a new entry to the array while editMode is enabled. The move indicators for new items did not appear even if the value inside moveDisabled is false, unless you have to refresh the whole listview using identifier.
I'll drop some code down here and an attachment with the problem. Please help me fix this. Sorry for the typos, Thanks in advance!!


//
//  AttributesReorderView.swift
//  OneApp
//
//  Created by Ligen Raj on 06/09/24.
//  Created for StackOverflow Questioning.
//

import SwiftUI

fileprivate struct ItemView: View {
    
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    @Binding var item: IdentifiableAttribute
    @FocusState.Binding var focused: Int?
    var index: Int?
    var disabled: Bool
    
    init(item: Binding<IdentifiableAttribute>, focused: FocusState<Int?>.Binding, index: Int?, disabled: Bool) {
        self._item = item
        self._focused = focused
        self.index = index
        self.disabled = disabled
    } //: INIT
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
            TextField("Add new item", text: $item.attribute.title)
                .focused($focused, equals: index)
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.words)
                .font(.medium)
            
            ColorPickerView
                .transition(.opacity)
                .active(if: !disabled)
            
            DividerView(color: .themeSecondary, width: 1)
                .padding(.vertical, 4)
                .hidden(disabled)
        } //: HSTACK
        .padding(8)
        .padding(.leading, 2)
        .background(alignment: .leading, content: BackgroundView)
        .overlay(alignment: .leading, content: {
            DividerView(color: item.color, width: 2)
        })
        .transition(.opacity)
        
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder private var ColorPickerView: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            Circle()
                .fill(item.color)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
                .background {
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 1)
                        .foregroundStyle(.themeSecondary)
                }
            
            ColorPicker(selection: $item.color, label: emptyView)
                .labelsHidden()
                .blendMode(.destinationOut)
                .compositingGroup()
        } //: ZSTACK
        .scaleEffect(0.8)
        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    } //: VIEW_VAR
    
    @ViewBuilder private func DividerView(color: Color, width: CGFloat) -> some View {
        Capsule()
            .fill(color)
            .frame(width: width)
    } //: VIEW_FUNC
    
    @ViewBuilder private func BackgroundView() -> some View {
        RoundedCorner(radius: 6, corners: [.topRight, .bottomRight])
            .fill(.themeDarkBlue)
            .frame(width: disabled ? nil : Helper.screenWidth - 16)
    } //: VIEW_FUNC
    
}

struct AttributesReorderView: View {
    
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel: AttributeReorderViewModel = .init()
    @State private var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
    @FocusState private var focused: Int?
    
    var items: [Attribute]
    var title: String
    
    init(items: [Attribute], title: String, type: String) {
        self.items = items
        self.title = title
        
        viewModel.type = type
    } //: INIT
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 8) {
            HeaderView
            
            List {
                ForEach($viewModel.items, id: \.id) { $item in
                    let isDisabled: Bool = viewModel.isTitleEmpty(item)
                    let index: Int? = viewModel.getIndex(item)
                    
                    ItemView(item: $item, focused: $focused, index: index, disabled: isDisabled)
// Not updating properly => .moveDisabled(isDisabled)
                        .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                            Button(role: .destructive, action: {
                                viewModel.onDelete(item)
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "trash")
                            } //: BUTTON
                            .active(if: !isDisabled)
                        }
                } //: LOOP
                .onMove(perform: viewModel.onMove)
            } //: LIST
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
            .emptyListBackground()
            .hideScrollContentIfAvailable()
            .animation(.easeIn, value: viewModel.items)
            .animation(.easeOut, value: editMode.isEditing)
            
            MinimalButtonView(title: "Done", action: {})
                .padding([.horizontal, .bottom])
        } //: VSTACK
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .customSheetBG(color: .themeBlack)
        .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
        .onAppear(perform: onAppear)
        .onReceive(viewModel.itemRemovedPublisher, perform: onReceiveItemRemovedAtIndex)
        .onSubmit(onSubmit)
        
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder private var HeaderView: some View {
        CommonNavBar(title: title, centerAligned: true, foregroundColor: .white)
            .overlay(alignment: .trailing, content: {
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                    PaddingButton(systemName: "plus", padding: 16, renderingMode: .template(.white), action: {
 // The problem is here => viewModel.appendAttribute()
                    })
                    .symbolRenderingMode(editMode.isEditing ? .palette : .hierarchical)
                    
                    PaddingButton(systemName: "square.and.pencil", padding: 16, renderingMode: .template(.white), action: {
                        editMode = editMode.isEditing ? .inactive : .active
                    })
                    .symbolRenderingMode(editMode.isEditing ? .palette : .hierarchical)
                }
            })
    } //: VIEW_VAR
    
    private func onAppear() {
        viewModel.items = viewModel.cast(items)
        
        guard !items.contains(where: \.title.isEmpty) else { return }
        
        viewModel.appendAttribute()
    } //: FUNC
    
    private func onSubmit() {
        guard focused != viewModel.items.indices.last else { return }
        
        focused = (focused ?? 0) + 1
    } //: FUNC
    
    func onReceiveItemRemovedAtIndex(_ index: Int?) {
        guard index != .zero else { return }
        
        focused = (index ?? 0) - 1
    } //: FUNC
    
}

// MARK: - PREVIEW

struct AttributeReorderPreviewView: View {
    
    @State private var items: [Attribute] = [.status1, .status2, .status3]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        AttributesReorderView(items: items, title: "Project Status", type: "status")
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    AttributeReorderPreviewView()
}



Feel free to ask any doubt about the code..
Any help regarding this will be appreciated.
